# Google Play Scraper not pulling all reviews when using 'reviews_all'

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

**UPDATE**

Just found out this is a known issue being tracked on Github
https://github.com/JoMingyu/google-play-scraper/issues/209

================================================

**Goal:**

I'm wanting to retrieve all the user reviews from a given app in the Google Play Store. (Note that I understand the difference between 'reviews' and 'ratings'.) However, currently, I'm not getting anywhere near the full number of reviews that should be available.

**What I've tried:**

Using this app as an example:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teladoc.members&pli=1

I can successfully pull down the App Detail data, and I see that this app has over 64,000 ratings, and over 27,000 reviews. I'm wanting to pull down all of the 27,000+ reviews.

Below is the 'App All Reviews' code I'm using, which I got from this page:
https://pypi.org/project/google-play-scraper/

**Code**

```
from google_play_scraper import Sort, reviews_all

results = reviews_all(
    'com.teladoc.members',
    sleep_milliseconds=0, # defaults to 0
    lang='en', # defaults to 'en'
    country='us', # defaults to 'us'
    sort=Sort.NEWEST, # defaults to Sort.MOST_RELEVANT
    filter_score_with=None # defaults to None(means all score)
)
```

**The result**

For the result, I'm getting a dictionary of 398 objects, one for each 'reviewId'. So 398 reviews instead of 27,000+.

This info is on the PyPI site, but I'm not clear what I need to do that the above code doesn't do?

```
:bulb: Because of the Google Play Store limit (up to 200 reviews can be fetched at a time), http requests are generated as long as the number of app reviews is divided by 200. For example, targeting an app like Pokémon GO makes tens of thousands of http requests.
```

Any input on how to download or scrape the full 27,000+ reviews will be greatly appreciated.

Thx